# In $\triangle ABC$, bisectors of $\angle B$ and $\angle C$ meet opposite sides at $D$ and $E$. If $\angle B<\angle C$, show $CE<BD$.

Tags: triangles, angle

> In $\triangle ABC$, $\angle B<\angle C$, and $BD$ and $CE$ are angle bisectors. $D$ is on $AC$ and $E$ is on $AB$. Prove that $CE<BD$.

Using the fact that $\angle B<\angle C$, I got that $AB>AC$ and $BF>CF$ (where $F$ is the intersection of the two angle bisectors).

I then expressed $CE=CF+FE$ and $BD=BF+DF$. Since $CF<BF$, we only have to prove that $FE<DF$. I tried to use the angle bisector theorem to get some relations that might help me prove that, but here's where I got stuck. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: I think you forgot to mention that $D$ is on the side $AC$ and $E$ is on the side $AB.$ Without some kind of information like that, it is not determined which length is greater.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. Do you have any idea about what I should do next?

Comment: This was also asked in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482409/angle-bisector-comparison#3482605 but no correct answers so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use theorem of sines on triangles $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACE$ to obtain:
$$\dfrac{BD}{\sin A} = \dfrac{AB}{\sin\left( A+\frac B2\right)},\quad \dfrac{CE}{\sin A} = \dfrac{AC}{\sin\left(A+\frac C2\right)}.$$
Combining these two yields:
$$\dfrac{BD}{CE} = \dfrac{AB}{AC}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\left( A+\frac C2\right)}{\sin\left( A+\frac B2\right)}$$
and the rest should be easy.